# Node.js Scrape datetime from a DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, web-scraping

I have a simple question.

I have this HTML code

```
  <time datetime="2014-02-18"> 18 February 2014</time>
```

How i can scrape the datetime in format "2014-02-18" ?

I tryed

```
var date = $('time').value;
```

or

```
var date = $('time').dateTime;
```

but both return undefined on console.

Thanks!

Comment: `var date = $('time').text();`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: That would be `"18 February 2014"`, not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

(I assume you're using jQuery in Node or cheerio or similar.)

You can get the string via `attr`:

```
var dateString = $('time').attr('datetime');
```

Then convert it to a date in your favorite way, being sure to allow for the right timezone. For instance, you could do

```
var date = new Date(dateString);
```

...after first checking what the version of V8 in your version of Node does with that, since unfortunately the specification floundered on it:

- It wasn't defined at all prior to ES5
- It was mis-defined in ES5 as being UTC if there's no timezone indicator instead of local time as per ISO-8601, so `"2014-02-18"` would have been UTC, but:
- That was fixed in ES2015, so `"2014-02-18"` would be interpreted as local time, but:
- And then updated in ES2016 to say that *date-only* forms should be UTC and *date-time* forms should be local time, so `"2014-02-18"` would be UTC again

So just be sure you know what your copy of V8 is doing if you use that, or use `new Date(year, month, day)` (for local time) or `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month day))` (for UTC) to handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

time is not a value field so .value will not work.

In javascript you can use ,

```
document.getElementsByTagName("time")[0].getAttribute("datetime");
```

And if you are using JQuery you can use,

```
$('time').attr('datetime')
```

datetime is basically an attribute of time field.

Comment: the second option also works for cheerio - thank you